# Solve 3x3 system linear algebra with no Gauss no Cramers

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

i want to ask if there are standars "steps" that i can follow to solve a 3x3 system only using algebra no Gauss method or something else.For example (1) `3x+y+4z=5` , ( 2) `6x+2y+6z=7` , (3) `7x+5y+2z=8`.First , i will take two of those lets say i take (1) and (2).After this i will try to erase y(may for another exercise i will try to erase another variable x or z).After this,i will solve this exercise for x(or z).I will show you what i mean ,(1) and (2) i will add,but first i will multiple the (1) with -2 so will be -6x-2y-8z=5(4).Now i will add it (4) with the (2) and i will have z=-12/2=6.This is the logic i should working at to find the result(with not using gauss only algebra) to solve every similar exercise?Thanks

Comment: What you performed _is_ Gaussian elimination, just less efficient.

Comment: ... and Gaussian elimination *is* algebra.

Comment: Or the beautifulest of all, the [Cramer Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), which is just an explicit solution for any linear problem, using determinants. Nothing can be more algebraic than that!.

Comment: ok sorry.can you solve it with not use Gaussian elimination or the cramer rule?